# Get "Connection refused" when connect mysql server built by docker

Tags: mysql, docker

I built php-apache and mysql containers by docker. This is my docker-compose.yml

```
voc_server:
  image: php:apache
  container_name: voc_server
  working_dir: /var/www/html
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html
  links:
    - voc_mysql
voc_mysql:
  image: mysql:5
  container_name: voc_mysql
  ports:
      - "3307:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

I run docker-compose up and they started perfectly. I can access mysql by workbench. This is my php code :

```
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1:3306";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

I got this error

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in
>   /var/www/html/index.php on line 7
>       Connection failed: Connection refused

Any thoughts? What can be my issue?

Comment: In your code shouldn’t the server name be 127.0.0.1:3306?

Comment: Sorry. Edit to 3306 still not works

Comment: In a docker-compose file, you have to provide a network, so both containers would run on the same network.  For connection to MySQL, you have to use service name ("voc_mysql")  instead of "127.0.0.1". So your URL of Mysql would be "voc_mysql:3306".

Comment: @Sargar sorry how to provide a network in docker-compose file please? Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the port number in your code should be 3306 instead of 3307 127.0.0.1:3306

Answer (score 0):

`$servername` should not be `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, but the name of the service.

Please set `$servername` in PHP to `voc_mysql` (And i think the port is useless as 3306 is the mysql default one so PDO will guess it.

if you want a deeper example/explanation, please read this article ;)
https://doc4dev.com/en/create-a-web-site-php-apache-mysql-in-5-minutes-with-docker/